# How to change the background-color of the parent class by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to make a bootstrap carousel with `.carousel-indicators` positioned `relative`.
However, because of this, I cannot set the `background-color` of each carousel item different 
since it can't be applied to the upper part where indicators are positioned.
So I am trying to apply the `background-color` attribute to the parent class instead.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators text-left">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <div id="item0" class="item active">
      </div>
      <div id="item1" class="item">
      </div>
      <div id="item2" class="item">
      </div>
      <div id="item3" class="item">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And below is the jQuery code that I've tried,
But it doesn't work and I'm wondering why.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#item2").hasClass('active')) {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color, '#d4ddde');
    }
    else {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color, 'none');
    }
});
```

I edited the jQuery grammar but still doesn't work.

Comment: I think the reason why it doesn't work is because your code is executed just one time. So when bootstrap add the class `active` to item2, your code is not re-executed

Comment: @Riverside Thx for the tip! I corrected the jquery grammar but still doesn't work. Can you tell me how I can re-execute the codes?

Comment: Check my answer, and tell me if it's work ;)

Comment: @Riverside Wow it works perfectly! thank u so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, your code is executed just one time at the opening of your page. So when the carousel slides, and Bootstrap adds the `active` class to his items, you code is not re-executed. You have to use the callbacks functions that provide you Bootstrap.

The Bootstrap's carousel plugin fire 2 events when the slides move :

- **slide** : This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
- **slid** : This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

So if you want to watch what's happened during the transition or if you want to add a class to whatever you want, you may want to use these events.

**Let's see the code :**

This is how you can add and watch these events with jQuery :

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide', function() {
    //Do something before the animation
});

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid', function() {
    //Do something after the animation
});​​
```

**In your case :**

This code below should fix your problem :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide', function() {
        if ($("#item2").hasClass('active')) {
            $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color, '#d4ddde');
        }
        else {
            $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

*Here's official bootstrap's carousel doc :* http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

Answer (score 2):

jquery [**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) and [**css**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp) usage in question is incorrect. Use following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#item2").hasClass('active')) {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color','#d4ddde');
    }
    else {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color','transparent');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#item2").hasClass('active')) {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color', '#d4ddde');
    }
    else {
        $(".carousel-inner").css('background-color' , 'none');
    }
});
```

Documentation for **.hasClass** : [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Documentation for **.css** : [here](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value)